# How to set a more complex default value for a JSONB column in sqlAlchemy (postgreSQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm adding a new column to a table of type JSONB and I can not find the formatting necissary to set the default value to anything other than a empty object.

How would I accomplish this?

Currently my code looks akin to:
`new_column     = db.Column(JSONB, server_default=db.text("'{}'"), nullable=False)`

I've tried a few ways I thought might be the intuitive way of handeling it. But so far they just cause an error when being run.

Example 1:
`new_column     = db.Column(JSONB, server_default=db.text("'{'enabled': True}'"), nullable=False)`

Example 2:
`new_column     = db.Column(JSONB, server_default=db.text("'{enabled: True}'"), nullable=False)`

Comment: Your default attempts are not valid JSON. In JSON keys are strings, and strings must be double quoted.

Comment: This was basically the answer. I posted a more detailed solution bellow for others to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ilja Everilä's answer was the answer.  In python I had to format the line of code in the style of:

`server_default=db.text("'{\"enabled\": \"true\"}'")`

Tripple quotes work too if you don't want escape characters, but this looks nicer to my eyes

Still unsure how I would pass the booleen value of true instead of a string. But that is another question for another time.

Comment: The JSON syntax for booleans is `true` and `false`, in all lower case, so just remove the quotes. In your original you had used `True`, perhaps following Python :)

Comment: I think I did try that. But that code is currently out of my hands, so I can't really check or try again. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the solution isn't to pass a thing that Python knows will convert to JSON rather than something that's already JSON-encoded:

```
new_column = db.Column(JSONB, server_default={'enabled': True}, nullable=False)
```

And maybe you need to set the regular default too:

```
default = {'enabled': True}
new_column = db.Column(JSONB, default=default, server_default=default, nullable=False)
```

If these suggestions don't help you'll probably need to post your error messages so that people can better understand what's going wrong.  "It throws an error" doesn't help understand where things go wrong, which is crucial to figure out how to get them to go right.